# How to get text in angle brackets with lxml or bs

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, lxml

I want to extract text in angle brackets like:

```
<p><verb></p>
```

The result should be `<verb>`.

lxml and bs4 don't work on this situation and it seems they take `<verb>` as a html tag. They cannot parse the text from the angle brackets, and just return empty string.

So, any solutions? THX!

Comment: These libs do the right thing. A word in angle brackets in a XML document is **not** text, it is an element. If you want to parse your document with an XML parser, use the XML syntax appropriately (here, to get the result you want, should be `<p>&lt;verb&gt;</p>`.

Comment: you can also use `regex`

Comment: @spectras Actually, I'm not the web page builder. The builder doesn't mean to make it as a HTML tag and uses angle brackets instead of &lt or &gt just for simplicity.  I think the libs ought to check the legality of tags. I just wanna extract it which is among a number of p tags. The missing text is important for structuring subsequent text.

Comment: @SimmerChan> the tags **are** legal. XML allows arbitrary elements in documents. When you say that *¨The builder doesn't mean to make it as a HTML tag and uses angle brackets instead of &lt or &gt just for simplicity”*, you're just saying the builder used a syntax that *looks like* HTML but *isn't* HTML. No wonder then that an HTML parser doesn't give the results you want: you're no longer parsing HTML but a custom language that looks like it. It would be like writing `**this**` in your question and complaining that the website takes it as bold, while you meant it as raw asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import re
my_str = "<p><verb></p>"
my_new_string = re.sub('[\<p\>|\<\/p\>]', '', my_str)
print my_new_string
```

output: verb

Comment: Actually I don't want to use re. The example p tag is among a number of p tags, which means I have to locate the example p tag and then use re. I just wonder whether I can deal with the example p tag with other normal p tags, using consistent method instead of different strategies.THX! anaway